# Can't Select A Cell In Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a simple noob question, but it is vexing me. Following a tutorial, I want to select the first value in column "A". The tutorial says run `print(df[0]['A'])` but Python3 gives me an error. However, it works perfectly if I use `print(df[0:1]['A'])`. Why is that?

Here is the full code for replication:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

print(df[0:1]['A'])
```

Answer (score 3):

because `df[0]['A']` means column `0` at index `A`; you need to use `df.iloc[0]['A']`, or `df['A'][0]`, or `df.ix[0]['A']`

see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for the indexing and slicing.

see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for when you get a copy as opposed to a view.

Comment: or simply `df.ix[0,'A']`

Comment: and note, `df[0]['A']` in fact is meaningless, as this syntax accesses columns by name, and no column with name `0` in df is present.

Answer (score 3):

See the [selecting ranges](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) section of the docs. As mentioned:

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of `[]` slices the rows. This is provided largely as a convenience since it is such a common operation.

The flip side being that this is inconsistent.

It's worth mentioning that you can often be explicit with loc/iloc:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df['A']
Out[12]: 
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [13]: df.loc[:, 'A']  # equivalently
Out[13]: 
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [14]: df.iloc[:, 0]  # accessing column by position
Out[14]: 
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

It's worth mentioning another inconsistency with slicing:

```
In [15]: df.loc[0:1, 'A']
Out[15]: 
0    1
1    3
dtype: int64

In [16]: df.iloc[0:1, 0]  # doesn't include 1th row
Out[16]: 
0    1
dtype: int64
```

To select with a position and a label use ix:

```
In [17]: df.ix[0:1, 'A']
Out[17]: 
0    1
1    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

*Note labels take precedence with ix.*

It's worth emphasising that assignment is garaunteed to work with one loc/iloc/ix, but **may** fail when chaining:

```
In [18]: df.ix[0:1, 'A'] = 7  # works

In [19]: df['A'][0:1] = 7  # *sometimes* works, avoid!
```

Comment: Andy, re the chaining, DF[col][row] should be avoided is that right, or is it only when slicing as well i.e. DF[col][row1:row2] ??

Comment: @WoodyPride if you're doing assignment chaining is not guaranteed to work. I would avoid `DF[col][row]` :)

Comment: That comes as a blow! I now have to go back and check a year's worth of work. Ooops!

Comment: @WoodyPride is [mentioned in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) "This can work at times, but is not guaranteed, and so should be avoided", definitely worth checking since if it fails - it fails silently.

Comment: Agreed, sadly I read the docs looking for the info I wanted not the info I needed!